# Sort 2D array without using Arrays.sort()

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to sort the entire array from least to greatest, but I can’t use any methods such as `Arrays.sort()`. So far I have only been able to create array. An example of my output would be

The original array is:

```
74  7  71
59  4  37
```

The sorted array is:

```
 4   7  37
59  71  74
```

```java
import java.util.Random;

public class arrays2d2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Random rand = new Random();

        int[][] array2D = new int[3][3];

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("The original array is: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < array2D.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array2D[i].length; j++) {
                array2D[i][j] = rand.nextInt(100);
                System.out.print(array2D[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("");

        System.out.println("The sorted array is: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < array2D.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array2D[i].length; j++)
                System.out.print(array2D[i][j] + " ");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use ArrayList.sort using comparators. see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Comment: There are ways to do this, but first off, why are you using a multi-dimensional array? From your question, I think you may be confused about when/where to use a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: Yep, agree with @ControlAltDel. You should only use multidimensional arrays when strictly needed such as in tables or maps because it is simpler to work with 1-dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of methods to do this.

You can use `Arrays.sort` copying the 2-dimensional array in a 1-dimensional array:

```
int[] copy = new int[array2d.length * array2d[0].length]; //creates the copy array
for(int i = 0; i < array2d.length; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < array2d[0].length; j++)
       copy[i*array2d.length + j] = array2d[i][j];

Arrays.sort(copy);

for(int i = 0; i < array2d.length; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < array2d[0].length; j++)
       array2d[i][j] = copy[i*array2d.length + j];
```

Note that this algorithm only works with rectangular arrays (like yours)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the for loop to sort arrays:

```
int matriks1[][] = {
        {12,21,9},
        {17,6,4},
        {25,56,78}
    };
    int temp;
    for(int i=0;i<matriks1.length;i++){
        for(int j=0; j<matriks1.length;j++){
            for(int k =0; k<matriks1.length;k++){
                for(int l = 0; l<matriks1.length; l++){
                    if(matriks1[i][j] < matriks1[k][l]){
                    temp = matriks1[k][l];
                    matriks1[k][l] = matriks1[i][j];
                    matriks1[i][j]=temp;
                    }
                }   
            }
        }
    }
```

Output :

```
4 6 9
12 17 21
25 56 78
```